# Make ID negative in a JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I have this query

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 AS t1 LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
```

I want to consider "t1.id" (INT type) as negative so basically i simply have to add "-" before "320". I tryed with something like this with no success:

```
t2.id = 't1.'-'id'
```

How can i make it?

Comment: It's simple, you should do something like: "t2.id = t1.id * -1"

Comment: I have already tryed with no success. It seems that it doesn't work in a JOIN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a simple multiplication:

```
t2.id = -1 * t1.id'
```

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work in the join. If i make ON t2.id = '-321' it works but with ON t2.id = -1 * t1.id it doesn't. No syntax errors. It's just that i don't get the JOIN.

Comment: I've tested it, it worke. what is the column type of your id column?

Comment: Argh got it! 1300 lines of code to get that id and $ was missing inside the query. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply by -1

`t2.id = -1 * t1.id`